# Can I upload this SalesforceSans font as a static resource and then call it in a VF page?

Tags: visualforce, static-resources, lightning, lightning-design-system

I've downloaded the [Lightning Design System](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/) and I'd like to just upload the SalesforecSans font to my dev org for now, preferably as a static resource.

Is this possible?

How would I then call this font in an Visualforce page?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could put them in a .zip folder, upload them as a static resource and use `@font-face` to call them in your CSS.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: myFont;
    src: url({!URLFOR($Resource.MyZipFile, '/root/to/font.ttf')});
}

p {
    font-family: myFont;
}
```

In `@font-face` you're created a font giving it a name and the directory to your font. Then in `p` you're simply using the font you've referenced.

Comment: @Daft Let me know if this works. This is how web devs who want to store fonts locally do it, so I shouldn't think Salesforce would be any different. I've called different fonts using CDNs so this should work!

Comment: not working for me . any idea?